# How to get data from SQL To excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

My sql query is running fine but when I export the data to excel it gives 
warning : null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. How to fix this issue?

Comment: If you could post your query we may have a better chance at answering.

Comment: Maybe you should post the query? How shall we know what you are trying to do if you just tell us that error message..

Answer (score 4):

Really it's just a warning indicating some aggregated data are NULLs. For example average of `{10, null, 20}` is `(10+20)/2=15`, null is totally ignored. If it's OK, just ignore the warning or `set ansi_warnings off` to turn it off. Otherwise check your data for NULLs or change the query accordingly.